# file open and file save

Tags: python, file, save

I am having problems finding the right documentation on how to open a file in a given folder for reading and how to save an output file to a given folder. I would appreciate if someone could explain it to me or point in the right direction.

I have to open a file of tagged words, one word and its tag per line, that I will use to check my code, then I will have to create a similar file, using a text file and my code.

Comment: This may help: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/04/python-101-how-to-open-a-file-or-program/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Become good friends with http://docs.python.org

Second I would recommend to take a basics course on f.ex. 
http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python